# Rails - How to add additional column value into Devise registration table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

**User Model**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :tenant, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**Tenant Model**

```
class Tenant < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :users
end
```

**Controller**

Workaround 1 (not working)

```
def create
    super

    @tenant = Tenant.new
    @user = @tenant.build_user(params)
    @tenant.save
end
```

Workaround 2 (not working)

```
def create
    @tenant = Tenant.new
    @user = User.build(params)
    @tenant.save

    super

end
```

Is there any possibilities to pass a parameter to devise super class?

Since Devise super method has its own functionality on user registration/password hashing/, I can not completely override the function.

I know the way I am saving is wrong, please suggest me the better approach.

**Actual source code:**

> (with Controller, Model, Migrations and Routes files are added.)

https://repl.it/@aravin/HarmlessRepentantHarddrive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override the [`sign_up_params`](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/Devise%2FRegistrationsController%3Asign_up_params) in your controller:

```
class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController

  private

  def sign_up_params    
    params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation...).merge({tenant_id: Tenant.create!.id})
  end
end
```

Comment: It is important to note that you will need the default fields :email, :password, :password_confirmation in this override 'sign_up_params' method as well as your new fields. Also, to override the edit method in devise you will want to define an 'account_update_params' method in the same fashion as shown above but it will require your new fields plus :email, :password, :password_confirmation, AND :current_password fields in the whitelisted parameters.

Comment: @Aravin what is not working? What errors are you getting?

Comment: Able to sign up the user. But tenant_id field remains empty. tenant_id is not populated. @AbM

Comment: @Aravin did you update your route to point to the custom registration controller that you created? Can you  paste the latest code you have in the question?

Comment: @AbM, Updated the question (with Controller, Model, Migrations and Routes files are added.)

Kindly check.

Comment: @Aravin You seem to be using `configure_sign_up_params` instead of `sign_up_params`

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to provide a little more verbose answer than was provided by [AbM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2697183/abm).

1. You can generate the registrations_controller.rb file with the following command:

   `rails g devise:controllers users -c=registrations`
2. Once you do this, you will want to modify it such that you have something like:

   ```
   class RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
       private

       def sign_up_params
           params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
       end

       def account_update_params
           params.require(:user).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password)
       end
   end
   ```
3. Then in your routes.rb file you will want to change the devise_for line to tell devise that you want to override your registrations controller like:

   `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: 'users/registrations' }`

   Of course, you will want to **replace the :user/:users references** to the name of your devise authentication model if you are using something other than the standard User throughout my example.

[Here is a reference to this in the official docs on GitHub](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/Tool:-Generate-and-customize-controllers).