# Best practise for user management in Rails Association?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 4 table, I cannot conclude the best practise for my table using Rails Active Record Association as per document : https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html

1. Tenant
2. Tenant Details
3. User
4. User Details

**Information about table,**

`User` belongs to `Tenant`

`Tenant` has many `User`

`Tenant` has one `Tenant Info`

`User` has on `User Info`

---

I need to create Tenant & then I have to map the tenant id to the user table.

Please suggest me the best practise for association.

---

*Attahced my project skeleton here* https://repl.it/@aravin/HarmlessRepentantHarddrive

---

*My previous & similar question* [Rails - How to add additional column value into Devise registration table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54242759/rails-how-to-add-additional-column-value-into-devise-registration-table#)

Comment: Is there a particular reason why `TenantInfo` exists? Same for `UserInfo`. Maybe the columns in `TenantInfo` (and `UserInfo`) can live in the `Tenant`'s (and `User`'s) table?

Comment: Just ignore tenantInfo & userInfo. Primary goal is to achieve tenant & user.

Comment: In that case, you got it right: `Tenant has_many :users` and `User belongs_to :tenant`, meaning that the foreign key lives in `users` table as column `tenant_id`

Comment: Yeah.. but after my association.. I am able to create user within tenant id. It is wrong.. I have to build user using tenant's id

Comment: @Aravin, not sure, if I understand you. "I have to build user using tenant's id" - with  MrYoshiji's association you create a user and store tenant's id in user's `tenant_id` column. What's wrong with it?